# is it possible repeat rows of table in pdf file with pdfmake.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf, pdfmake

Is it possible torepeat rows in table generated in pdf with pdfmake.min.js?
I am creating a PDF file. in which  I need to repeat row of table according my api response, which is an array of object.

```
var dd = {content: [
                    {   
                     table: {
                        body: [
                               [ 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'],
                               [ '1', '2', '3'],
                               [ '1', '2', '3']
                              ]
                            }
                    }
                   ]
         };
```

This is the simple way of creating table with pdfmake.
my question is can we use any alternative(like ng-repeat) to repeat large data in table's rows?
I got the best way to generate pdf is with pdfmake. suggest me how to repeat table rows.

Comment: `ng-repeat` relies on data array in your model. Map that data into your pdf structure. Not clear what specific problem is

Comment: i have a large  array of  objects. I need to use the data from those objects into rows of this table.
I cant add row manually in my pdf file. So i need to know if there any method is available or not?
Assume you have to add row 100 rows ion your pdf file, then how would you do it. you cant add every row in table manually.

Comment: Then you need to map your response array to use property you want in each column

Comment: Thank you so much but how??

Comment: Why is jspdf and jspdf-autotable tagged? Seems like the question is about pdfmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I assume you are creating your pdf like:
`pdfMake.createPdf(dd).open();`

where the `dd` variable is basically just a simple javascript object. You can extend that any way you want with arrays, and whatnot, for example:

```
var
  body = [],
  content = [],
  dd = {
    'content' : content 
  };

body.push(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']);

var secondRow = [];

// Push numbers 0, 1, 2
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  secondRow.push("i is:" + i);
}

body.push(secondRow);

// ...
// Manipulate the 'body' any way you want.
// ...

// Lets push the manipulated body into the 'content'
// which is already inside the 'dd'.
content.push({
  'table' : {
    'body' : body
  }
});

// Now with all the manipulated data, create the pdf.
pdfMake.createPdf(dd).open();
```

So the point is, to manipulate this js object the way you want, when you are all set and done, call the `createPdf`.

If you paste my script into [pdfmake-playground](http://bpampuch.github.io/pdfmake/playground.html), you can see what I mean.

Comment: hi , is there any way to create table with in table, in makepdf. that is i have 2 rows . First row with 5 columns , in the second row  i need another table with 8 columns. I there any way to create a json as in makepdf.